# Wordpress Plugin Captain Slider loading

Tags: wordpress

I am using **captain slider** plugin in order to add slider to my site I want to know is it loading images one by one or it loads all images and then display any idea?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the code or looked at your browser's console?

Comment: I have looked the code there is a simple php file and js file no I can not get any idea from that???

Comment: Have you already tried analyzing the transmitted Network Data? I usually do this with [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) / Firefox. I can check it out later.